# instantclick slim-lang syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I am trying to add [instantclick](http://instantclick.io/download) to my rails app and I have [slim-lang](http://slim-lang.com/) question.

How do I convert this code to acceptable [slim-lang](http://slim-lang.com/) syntax?

```
<script src="instantclick.min.js" data-no-instant></script>
<script data-no-instant>InstantClick.init();</script>
```

Right now I am working with this:

```
script[src="/assets/javascripts/plugins/instantclick.min.js" data-no-instant]
|<script data-no-instant>InstantClick.init();</script>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can something like this:

```
script data-no-instant="" src="/assets/javascripts/plugins/instantclick.min.js" 
script data-no-instant=""  InstantClick.init();
```

Or:

```
script data-no-instant="" src="/assets/javascripts/plugins/instantclick.min.js" 
script data-no-instant="" 
  | InstantClick.init();
```